# Trying to implement the Binary Search algorithm, can't seem to get it to work

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I've been trying for the past hour to get this binary search algorithm to work and by using an example of the algorithm as explained on khan academy, I still can't get it to work, it should output a number but nothing happens. The  example on khan academy is like this:

> 1. Let min = 0 and max = n-1.
> 2. If max < min, then stop: target is not present in array. Return -1.
> 3. Compute guess as the average of max and min, rounded down (so that it is an integer).
> 4. If array[guess] equals target, then stop. You found it! Return guess.
> 5. If the guess was too low, that is, array[guess] < target, then set min = guess + 1.
> 6. Otherwise, the guess was too high. Set max = guess - 1.
> 7. Go back to step 2.

And the code I wrote according to the steps is:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
int arr[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97 };
int min = 0;
int max = 24;
int guess;
int targetValue = 73;
while (max > min) {
    guess = ((max + min) / 2);
    if (arr[guess] == targetValue) {
        std::cout << guess;
        break;
    }
    else if (arr[guess] < targetValue) {
        min = guess + 1;
    }
    else {
        max = guess - 1;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just as a remark, you should write `std::cout << guess << std::endl`, so that the output buffer is flushed.

Comment: add `std::cout << min << " " << max << std::endl;` as the first line in the `while` loop and it should help you in diagnosing.. you'll see that this program right now halts at `min=max=20`

Comment: Note that  "stop when `max < min`" is not the same as "go on as long as `max > min`". The negation of a < b is not a > b.

Comment: The easiest probably would've been to find one of the thousands of binary search implementations out there and compare your code to that. The better alternative would've been to **debug** your code.

Answer (score 2):

The binary search algorithm states

> If L > R, the search terminates as unsuccessful.

In your implementation however, you terminate the search on the condition L >= R. In the case of L == R, the algorithm should do one more iteration, because it did not consider this position in the list yet.

In your case of target value 73, when the algorithm reaches the position of the target, 20, L == R. Your implementation terminates one step too early to recognize the target.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

(max > min) to (max >= min)